# What is the best way to initialize a static object that I want to be shared across multiple threads

Tags: java

EDIT: Adding more context and code here:

Currently this is what I have:

```
public class MyClass{

   private static MyClass2 mySharedObject = null; //this is the object that I want to share across m

   private SomeRandomClass someRandomClass; 

   public MyClass(MyClass3 object3, MyClass4 object4, SomeRandomClass someRandomClass){


 /* it just so happens that it is guaranteed that someRandomClass, no 
    matter which thread creates it, will have the same value.  But the value is not known in design time and hence I can't move this initialize code to the static {} block, as suggested by many folks.  One thing that I can do is move the creation of this sharedObject outside MyClass and do it before any threads actually use it.  Unfortunately, I am dealing with a legacy code here and didn't want to do that change and that's why asked if the approach I presented is good enough or there is something better? */  


        this.someRandomClass = someRandomClass;

        synchronized(mySharedObject){

              if(mySharedObject ! =null){
                 mySharedObject = new MyClass2(someRandomClass);//It doesn't matter which thread wins to create this object. I just need a valid instance of someRandomClass to create mySharedObject.  Once it is created, I can use it for all the threads.
               }

        }

   }

}
```

Is there a better way?
PS: I don't want to pass this shared object in the constructor of MyClass and/or I don't want to make MyClass2 as singleton.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use a static initializer block?

Comment: because of this line:  mySharedObject = new MyClass2(someRandomClass);

Comment: What is the purpose of passing a reference to the current class to the static variable constructor? Besides the fact that it sort of defeats the purpose of a static variable, that's just _begging_ to run into concurrency issues.

Comment: @httpdigest: this is only for optmization.  Something I should have added - No matter which threads win, I just want  a single instance of sharedObject to be shared.  It doesn't really matter what value of "someRandomClass" is takes.

Comment: If it doesn't matter which someRandomClass is used, why not move its creation to inside a static initializer block?

Comment: because I cant use mySharedObject = new MyClass2(new MyClass2());

I have over simplied the actual situation here.  But what I really need is some valid instance of MyClass2 to initialize mySharedObject

Comment: downvoters, care to explain?  If there is something inherently stupid about this question, please let me know and I would close it.

Comment: That being the case, please [edit] your question to update the code to be that way.  Right now it's quite unclear exactly what your requirements and limitations are, and why they are that way.

Comment: I'm not sure about "stupid" (your words) but the question itself is sparse on detail, motivation, current code structure... background information that would make your question clearer

Comment: The reason for the downvotes might be because, in your attempt to make a [mcve], you have eliminated too much and so we can't understand why you want it to do what you are saying. As worded, the logical answer for the question is "use an initializer block", but all you are saying is that you can't and being really vague as to why not. Without more context, we can't suggest a better solution, which makes this a poor quality question.

Comment: @httpdigest yes, exactly.  The thing is - it is a legacy code and the actual constructor takes a lot of parameters in input.  The parameter that is used to create sharedObject is guaranteed to be the SAME across all the thread.  I have 1 choices here - either move this static shared object away from constructor and create it before any of the threads actually access this object.  But this will require a hell ton of changes and I was trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a static initializer block.

```
public class MyClass {
    private static MyClass2 mySharedObject;

    static {
        mySharedObject = null; // whatever value here
    }

    // The rest of MyClass
}
```

---

EDIT: From your comments, another approach is that you set the value of `mySharedObject` externally before you begin whatever concurrent process you are attempting:

```
/* MyClass.java */

public class MyClass {
    private static MyClass2 mySharedObject = null;

    public static SetSharedObject(MyClass2 sharedObject) {
        mySharedObject = sharedObject;
    }

    // The rest of the class
}

/* Elsewhere.java */

MyClass2 sharedObject = new MyClass2(someRandomClass);
MyClass.SetSharedObject(sharedObject);    

// Do whatever you do with MyClass concurrency
```

Comment: Can't use it.  Please see above: I want to use parameters passed in the constructor in the initialization of this shared object: mySharedObject = new MyClass2(someRandomClass);

Comment: @Tintin Then you are going to be in for a bad time. Changing the state of a shared static object from different threads is just asking for trouble. The shared object is meant to be referenced by multiple threads, so it needs to be initialized _before_ any of those threads are started. Having the threads responsible for the initialization means it is a crap-shoot as to which thread does the initialization, which can (and will) screw up the other threads.

Comment: @Tintin RE your "it doesn't matter what value 'someRandomClass' takes" comment, then it sounds like there's no reason the static object absolutely needs to be initialized in the constructor of `MyClass` anyway. In which case... use the static initializer block.

Comment: Its a legacy code.  I can't do: mySharedObject = new MyClass2(new MyClass2());  OR mySharedObject = new MyClass2(null);   which are the only choices I got if I were to move them into static block

Comment: @Tintin You could also have another static object that you initialize first before you pass it to the constructor. i.e. `rc = new SomeRandomClass(); mySharedObject = new MyClass2(rc);`

Comment: yeah to be truthful, this was my alternative.  But again, is the code that I put a bad one or is doomed to fail in some situation?

Comment: @Tintin If that object is _guaranteed_ to be the same object in every construction of `MyClass`, then **in theory** it would be fine to do what you're doing. But that is not a guarantee that it will go well, and keep in mind what you are doing is a dirty hack and will be considered _very_ bad practice. (Also, since you are synchronizing on `mySharedObject`, every thread is going to be waiting for every other thread to be done constructing their own version of `mySharedObject` before any work gets done, so you might run into performance issues there.)

Comment: Agreed on the bad practice part and I will not go ahead with this!  But coming to the code again, I used synchronized because I want to be sure that no 2 threads get mySharedObject = null and create their own objects.  Wasn't that the correct thing to do (keeping the hack thing aside...)? Thanks again for helping on this.

Comment: @Tintin Whenever you are changing the state of an object that is shared across threads, you want to use `synchronized` to prevent any other thread from accessing the object while it is uninitialized/unchanged or (potentially worse) partially initialized/changed. So yes, `synchronized` is proper for specifically that part of your code, but the only reason it is necessary is because of what you are trying to do (which, as has been established, is not an advisable way to do it).

Comment: Also regarding this "every thread is going to be waiting for every other thread to be done constructing their own version of mySharedObject before any work gets done".  --> threads will only wait to check if there is already a mySharedObject ( with null check).  The whole idea is they don't create mySharedObject of thier own and share the common one.